# MariaDB High CPU and RAM usage issue

Tags: centos, mariadb, zabbix

We have a zabbix server that is experiencing very high CPU consumption due to the mariadb service. This server (an AWS instance) was recently installed and it´s database was migrated from a previous version, as follows:

**Previous setup – CENTOS 7 + Zabbix Server 5.0.15 + MariaDB dist 5.5.60 + PHP 7.2.34
New setup – CENTOS 8 + Zabbix Server 5.4 + MariaDB dist 10.5 + PHP 7.3**

Once installed and migrated, the new server showing constant high CPU usage, even causing the server to crash. We than increased the server´s RAM as a workaround and increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size.

The presente hardware setup is: **2 cpu, 8GB RAM and 60GB disc**
The Zabbix Server has around **69 active hosts, 4813 active items and 147nvps.**

So far it is holding, but we still see CPU peaking frequently 80%-100% due to mariadb activity.

[top zabbix server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4M4L.png)

We made some more fine tuning adjustments to the mariadb configuration in na attempt to increase it´s performance, but it seemed to have had little effect. These adjustments are as follows:

> [mysqld] 
> datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
> max_connections = 400 
> max_allowed_packet=1024M 
> thread_pool_idle_timeout=7200 
> wait_timeout=120 
> interactive_timeout=300 
> innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2 
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=4831838208 
> innodb_file_per_table 
> innodb_log_file_size=64M 
> join_buffer_size=256k 
> read_buffer_size=256k 
> read_rnd_buffer_size=256k 
> table_cache=256 
> tmp_table_size=256M 
> max_heap_table_size=256M 
> query_cache_size=1M 
> thread_cache_size=300 
> [mariadb] 
> log_error=/var/log/mariadb/error.log 
> #log_queries_not_using_indexes=/var/log/mariadb/not_using_indexes.log 
> slow_query_log=ON 
> slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb-slow.log

Also, we activated the slow query log and are seeing a recurrent query that takes 10-15 seconds to complete. Follows the query below:

**User@Host: zabbix[zabbix] @ localhost []
Thread_id: 858953 Schema: zabbix QC_hit: No
Query_time: 22.167967 Lock_time: 0.000246 Rows_sent: 25 Rows_examined: 4003131
Rows_affected: 0 Bytes_sent: 3134
SET timestamp=1635358056;**

`SELECT a.alertid,a.clock,a.sendto,a.subject,a.message,a.s tatus,a.retries,a.error,a.userid,a.actionid,a.medi atypeid,a.alerttype FROM alerts a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM events e,functions f,items i,hosts_groups hgg JOIN rights r ON r.id=hgg.groupid AND r.groupid=14 WHERE a.eventid=e.eventid AND e.objectid=f.triggerid AND f.itemid=i.itemid AND i.hostid=hgg.hostid GROUP BY f.triggerid HAVING MIN(r.permission)>0 AND MAX(r.permission)>='2') AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM actions aa WHERE a.actionid=aa.actionid AND aa.eventsource='0') AND (a.userid IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM users_groups ug WHERE ug.userid=a.userid AND ug.usrgrpid=14)) ORDER BY a.clock DESC LIMIT 25;`

Considering the scenario described above, could anyone kindly confirm:

- Is this query is running as expected? Does it have any influence on the problem reported?
- Is there anymore fine tuning that can be done to mariadb in order to optimize it´s CPU performance? Is there anything inaccurately configured?

Any help will be very appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Best regards!

Comment: 1) asking multiple questions in a single post is an explicit close reason. Please focus your question on one problem only. 2) We cannot tell whether an arbitrary query runs as expected and we cannot tell what influence it may have on the high CPU utilisation. 3) tweking a database server settings is not a programming question, but a DBA one. Therefore the 2nd question should really be asked on the DBA sister site of SO.

Comment: That cpu spike might be the Zabbix housekeeping. Evaluate if you want to reinstall everything with PostgreSQL+TimescaleDB, instead of MySQL. The query is likely someone refreshing the Problems page, and it might take that long because of the housekeeping munching resources.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MariaDB Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful information includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.